# What is the cause of these empty Team Projects in Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, team-project

I have a peculiar problem within Visual Studio 2010, where all of a sudden my Team Projects within the Team Explorer window are empty and both display red crosses on their icons as can be seen in the attached image.

Can anyone help to explain why this is happening or how to find further information such as an error as no errors are displayed?

I have so far cleared the user settings through the Visual Studio 2010 command line, deleted all files from the Team Foundation cache folder from within my user account in Windows, uninstalled then reinstalled Visual Studio with SP1 and rebooted.

This seems isolated to the Team Explorer window, as I can browse and check out files using Source Control Explorer.

Thanks

[image: Screenshot of Team Explorer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally sorted it after a good few hours of head scratching and various attempts, it came down to either

```
C:\windows\system32 > regsvr32.exe /u actxprxy.dll
C:\windows\system32 > regsvr32.exe actxprxy.dll
```

or

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
```

I was running these to fix a problem in SQL Server 2010 Management Studio that I had encountered where I could not navigate databases so it must have been something internally to do with Windows Explorer. That information was found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/d5d3e5fc-d8ce-4f42-b7ea-9bbbb7756a20/).